# Get row number of UITableView in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my code I have a table view with many sections sorted alphabetically. I have `checkboxes(UIButton)` in table rows and I need check them according to respective status entered in row. I had done

```
checkbutton.tag = indexpath.row;
```

but when table scrolls and section get changed and I get status of previous section in my checkbox method. anyone please help me on this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   CheckButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [CheckButton addTarget:self action:@selector(CheckBoxAction:)      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   CheckButton.tag=indexPath.row;
   //some other stuff
   [cell.contentView addSubview:CheckButton];
}
```

and this my `CheckBoxAction`

```
-(void)CheckBoxAction:(UIButton *)btn
{
    tag = btn.tag;
    NSDictionary *tagdict =[statusArray objectAtIndex:tag]; 
}
```

Now, problem is that `indexpath.row` is 0 whenever section is changed, so I can't able to access exact row number in my `CheckBoxAction`.

Comment: Why are you creating checkbox buttons in that event, and not in getCellForRowAtIndex or interface builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this for getting current row you tap.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 CheckButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];

[CheckButton addTarget:self action:@selector(CheckBoxAction:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
CheckButton.tag=indexPath.row;
[cell addSubview:CheckButton];
}


-(void)CheckBoxAction:(id)sender
{
  // Cast Sender to UIButton
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

// Find Point in Superview
CGPoint pointInSuperview = [button.superview convertPoint:button.center toView:self.tableView];

// Infer Index Path
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInSuperview];

// Log to Console
NSLog(@"selected Row : %d", indexPath.row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

// Try this

```
CheckButton.tag = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row] integerValue];
```

**or**

// try this below link to get logic for, how to handle checkbox in UITableView

[Set checkmark in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419214/set-checkmark-in-uitableview/17419821#17419821)

Comment: This will get mess up when section are more than 9 and rows are more than 9 under sections.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is wrong in many ways. So, I am not going to give you a solution for the exact problem you have, but more of a guideline:

1. First you are adding the checkbox directly to the cell, which means you are possible adding multiple CheckButton to the same cell, if you scroll your `UITableView` a few times.
2. Add the checkButton on the cell directly instead of keep adding it in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, this can give you a performance boost.
3. Use a block that will be executed when a user clicks the button. This way you are able to capture the context of your `UIViewController`. You should assign that block to the cell on `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: can you please explain how to Add the checkButton on the cell directly instead of keep adding it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: You can either add in `awakeFromNib` inside your Cell. Or, if you don't have a NIB, you can add it init method of your cell. But again, this is not a concrete answer to your question, just more a guideline.

Comment: sir i can't understand.can you provide some link,tutorial or any type of help to add the checkButton on the cell directly