# iOS - Tableview with multiple sections - Show/Hide Accessory

Tags: ios, uitableview, accessoryview

I have an UITableView with multiple sections. I want to show/hide the checkmark accessory in the cell when the cell is clicked. I could have done this by using a MutableArray if there was only one section as mentioned in this answer [Set checkmark in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419214/set-checkmark-in-uitableview).
But how can I do it if there are multiple sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple sections, instead of an array, you can use... an array of arrays !

Comment: Can you please explain your answer with a sample code?

Comment: It's the same as the link you provide, only you repeat the same pattern - using a MutableArray with Booleans for 'checkmak' and some data object for the cell - but for each section. So basically, your build a MutableArray of MutableArray of dictionaries with Boolean & data object

Comment: Thanks. I just figured it out.