# When i scrolling on UITableview,the checkmark of multiple selected rows are disappears.how to solve this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, row, multipleselection

I want to implement multiple row selection in UITableview.but when i select multiple row with checkmark and scroll down,the checkmarks are disappears when i come back to selected rows section.I have tried many solutions from Stackoverflow but it doesn't work for me.Can you please anyone give me the solution which works for me.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }
            if([_selectedstatearray containsObject:indexPath]) {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }
            else {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

            }


        cell.textLabel.text = [statearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;

    }


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString *cellText = cell.textLabel.text;
        NSLog(@"cellText>>%@",cellText);

        if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
            [_selectedstatearray removeObject:cellText];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        } else {
            [_selectedstatearray addObject:cellText];
            cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }

        NSLog(@"selectedarray>>%@",_selectedstatearray);

        NSString *greeting = [_selectedstatearray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
        NSLog(@"%@",greeting);


        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


    }
```

Comment: are you allocating the memory of your `_selectedstatearray`

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419214/set-checkmark-in-uitableview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in this piece of code:

```
if([_selectedstatearray containsObject:indexPath]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

You are checking if _selectedstatearray contains the specified `indexPath` while you store them as NSString `[_selectedstatearray addObject:cellText];`

Replace the code above with this:

```
NSString *text = [statearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if([_selectedstatearray containsObject:text]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot.its working.and how to get this selected rows on other screen too?

Comment: @swapnilpatel You have to maintain array. Whenever user select any row you get indexPath of that row so store `indexPath.row` in array and pass that array to that VC where you want selected rows.

Comment: If you want this tableView to notify the other view controller when a row gets selected, you can either create a custom protocol and set delegate to that view controller or you can use a block. If all you want is just to access the selected row from the other view controller, you can simply declare `_selectedstatearray`  as a property in `.h` file.

Comment: selectedstatearray i already defined as property.then what?i have to pass these array to another viewcontroller?

Comment: If it is already a property of view controller A, you can simply access it from another view controller (View Controller B) by calling `viewcontrollerA.selectedstatearray`

Comment: @ The Mach System....after passing array to another viewcontroller,how to display that array's contents in uitableview as a check marked rows?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Answer for your last comment

If you are passing ***`selectedstatearray`*** to another `ViewController's` (viewControllerB) `UITableView` which will contain only **`selectedstatearray`** then you can just add

> cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark

At your UITableVIew delegate method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Which will add check-mark to all row's

Hope it helps....